# Bootstrap Scrollspy & Affix not responding with body margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to bootstrap and am experiencing with it for school.
However I got stuck. I found a nice navbar example using the Affix plugin, however when you scroll down affix won't apply the same margin rules I specified before.
Not sure if I explain it right, but i'll show you with a screenshot.

Situation 1: How it's before scrolling down (how it should be)

[image]

Situation 2: When I scroll down there appears a black box where the margin-right should be.

[image]

And here's my index.html (P.S. Snippet doesn't work because it doesn't have the bootstrap css and js)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
 position: relative; 
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-left:2em;
 margin-right:2em;
 }
 
.affix {
 top:0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 9999 !important;
 }
 
.navbar {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
 
.navbar-right {
 margin-right: 20em;
}
 
.affix ~ .container-fluid {
 position: relative;
 top: 50px;
 }
 
#biografie {
 padding-top:50px;
 height:40em;
 color: #fff; 
 background-color: #1E88E5;
 }
 
#portfolio {
 padding-top:50px;
 height:40em;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #673ab7;
 }
 
#contact {
 padding-top:50px;
 height:40em;
 color: #fff; 
 background-color: #ff9800;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap - Prebuilt Layout</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="30">
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
  <h1>Scrollspy & Affix Example</h1>
  <h3>Fixed navbar on scroll</h3>
  <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix" and data-spy="scrollspy".</p>
  <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels, and the links in the navbar are automatically updated based on scroll position.</p>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Homepage</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#biografie">Biografie</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="biografie" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Biografie</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that:

Change `width: 100%` in `affix` class to `width: calc(100% - 4em);` (because you have 2+2ems margin on body).